# Вид отношения между классами

Tags: c++

Как вы думаете, какой вид отношения между классами std::reference_wrapper и std::mutex?ref используется в виде обертки для обертки mutex'а, чтобы представить ее в виде ссылки ref(mx).

Comment: Агрегация......

Comment: Я считал, что это агрегация, но меня прост послали, хотя вполне логично, что оба класса друг без друга могут существовать, а включение тут явно по ссылке. Как вариант можно рассуждать, что это использование, т. к вполне себе тянет на то, mutex использует сервис ref по предоставлению себя ссылкой...или я ошибаюсь. Ведь часто зависимости показывают, что один класс использует другой класс как аргумент в сигнатуре своей операции.

Comment: Объект, на который ссылается `std::reference_wrapper`, никоим образом не принадлежит этому `std::reference_wrapper` и не является образующей частью этого `std::reference_wrapper`. Поэтому я бы здесь исключил из рассмотрения и композицию, и агрегацию. Тут скорее имеет место направленная ассоциация. Но все это такая нечеткая наука...